# how to properly rename com.company.tag_private

Tags: swift, swift3

My code is supposed to encrypt text with imported RSA certificate as .pem. I'm using RSAUtils.swift in the code, and I converted and imported both certificates as .pem but I havent done anything in .plist file (I'm not sure if something should be done or not) and the other doubdt that I have is about the com.company.tag_private line. What should I put there instead of 'company'? I tried with my name, but didn't work.
Everything seems to be fine (no errors) untill I launch the app and try to encrypt text, the just nothing happens - no text is output. What am I missing?

This is the code:

`

```
@IBOutlet weak var messageToDecrypt: UITextView!
@IBOutlet weak var decryptedMessageLabel: UITextView!

// tag name to access the stored private key stored in keychain
let privatekey = "com.company.tag_private"
// tag name to access the stored public key in keychain
let publickey = "com.company.tag_public"


@IBAction func decrypt(sender: AnyObject) {

    func decrypt() {

        let privatekey = getKeyStringFromPEM(name: "private_key_pkcs8")

        let message = messageToDecrypt.text
        let data = message?.data(using: String.Encoding(rawValue: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue))
        let decryptedData:NSData? = RSAUtils.decryptWithRSAPrivateKey(data!, privkeyBase64: privatekey, keychainTag: privatekey) as NSData?
        let decryptedMessage = decryptedData?.base64EncodedString(options: NSData.Base64EncodingOptions())


        decryptedMessageLabel.text = decryptedMessage
    }

}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    messageToDecrypt.delegate = self
    decryptedMessageLabel.delegate = self
}
```

`

Comment: Why are you using NSData? You are supposed to use Data in Swift 3

Comment: BTW `if let data = message?.data(using: .utf8) { ...`

Comment: `let decryptedData = RSAUtils.decryptWithRSAPrivateKey(data, privkeyBase64: privatekey, keychainTag: privatekey)`

Comment: Thank you for the reply @Leo Dabus! I did change it as you recommended, but still not working. I'll dig around and see if I can find what I'm doing wrong.